# SFINAE Based traits to determine if operator + is supported

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae, type-traits

Ηello 
I write a code in C++ using templates and  I try to implement a SFINAE what is fired when operator `+` is not supported. 
I write the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
class B
{
};
template<typename T1,typename T2>
struct IsSameT :std::false_type
{
    //static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template<typename T>
struct IsSameT<T,T> :std::true_type
{
    //static constexpr bool value = true;
};
template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct HasPlusT
{
    private:
    using T1_t = typename std::remove_reference<T1>::type;
    using T2_t = typename std::remove_reference<T2>::type;
    template<typename U1, typename = decltype(T1_t() + T2_t())>
    static char test(void *);
    template<typename>
    static long test(...);
    public:
    static constexpr  bool value = IsSameT<decltype(test<T1,T2>(nullptr)),char>::value;
};

template<typename T1,typename T2, bool = HasPlusT<T1,T2>::value>
struct PlusResultT
{
    using T1_t = typename std::remove_reference<T1>::type;
    using T2_t = typename std::remove_reference<T2>::type;
    using Type = decltype(T1_t() + T2_t());
};

template<typename T1,typename T2>
struct PlusResultT<T1,T2,false>
{
    using T1_t = typename std::remove_reference<T1>::type;
    using T2_t = typename std::remove_reference<T2>::type;
    using Type = decltype(T1_t() + T2_t());
};


int main()
{

    constexpr bool value = HasPlusT<B,B>::value;
    return 0;
}
```

I expect the `constexpr bool value = HasPlusT<B,B>::value` to return `false` but an error is generated
What is wrong in implementation?

> Class B has not an operator + and I expect that the constexpr bool value = >HasPlusT::value returns true. However a compilation error is generated
>   no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'HasPlusT::T1_t {aka B}' and >'HasPlusT::T2_t {aka B}')    Demo.cpp    /Demo       C/C++ >Problem

==============================================

New implementation to support class templates. Why the following implementatio fail to verify that operator + exists

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

template<typename T1,typename T2>
struct IsSameT :std::false_type
{
    //static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template<typename T>
struct IsSameT<T,T> :std::true_type
{
    //static constexpr bool value = true;
};

template<typename T, typename U>
struct IsFuntamentalHelper : IsSameT<T,U>
{
    //static constexpr bool value = IsSameT<T,U>::value;
};
template<typename T>
struct IsFundamentalT : std::false_type
{
    //static constexpr boo value = std::false_type;
};

template<>
struct IsFundamentalT<int> : IsFuntamentalHelper<int,int>
{

};
template<>
struct IsFundamentalT<float> : IsFuntamentalHelper<float,float>
{

};
template<>
struct IsFundamentalT<double> : IsFuntamentalHelper<double,double>
{

};
template<>
struct IsFundamentalT<long>: IsFuntamentalHelper<long,long>
{

};

template<typename T>
using enable_if_t = typename std::enable_if<IsFundamentalT<T>::value, T>::type;

template<typename T>
class A
{
public:
    template<typename = enable_if_t<T>>
    operator T()
    {
          return t ;
    }
    A<T>():t()
    {

    }
    template<typename = enable_if_t<T>>
    A<T>(T   a)
    {
        std::cout << "integer" << std::endl;
        this->t = a;
    }
    A<T>(A<T>  const & a)
    {
        this->t = a.t;

    }
public:
    A<T> add(A<T>  & a)
    {
        t += a.t;
        return *this;

    }
    friend  A<T>  operator + (A<T>   & a1, A<T>   &  a2)
    {

        return a1.add(a2);
    }
    T t;
};
template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct HasPlusT
{
    private:
    template <typename T>
          using Rr = typename std::remove_reference<T>::type;

          template<typename U1, typename U2>
      static auto test(void *)
         -> decltype(std::declval<Rr<U1>>() + std::declval<Rr<U2>>() , '0');

          template<typename...>
          static long test(...);

       public:
          static constexpr bool value
             = IsSameT<decltype(test<T1,T2>(nullptr)),char>::value;
};


template<typename T1,typename T2, bool = HasPlusT<T1,T2>::value>
struct PlusResultT
{
    using T1_t = typename std::remove_reference<T1>::type;
    using T2_t = typename std::remove_reference<T2>::type;
    using Type = decltype(T1_t() + T2_t());
};

template<typename T1,typename T2>
struct PlusResultT<T1,T2,false>
{
    using T1_t = typename std::remove_reference<T1>::type;
    using T2_t = typename std::remove_reference<T2>::type;
    using Type = decltype(T1_t() + T2_t());
};


int main()
{
    constexpr bool value = HasPlusT<A<int>,A<int>>::value;
    std::cout << value << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to write a template to check for a function's existence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct HasPlusT
 {
   private:
      template <typename T>
      using Rr = typename std::remove_reference<T>::type;

      template<typename U1, typename U2>
      static auto test(void *)
         -> decltype(std::declval<Rr<U1>>() + std::declval<Rr<U2>>() , '0');

      template<typename...>
      static long test(...);

   public:
      static constexpr bool value
         = IsSameT<decltype(test<T1,T2>(nullptr)),char>::value;
 };
```

I mean... your code has a couple of problems.

In no particular order.

1 - If you call `test<T1,T2>(nullptr)`, you explicitly pass two template types; so if you define `test` with a second type for the second parameter

```
template<typename U1, typename = decltype(T1_t() + T2_t())>
    static char test(void *);
```

the second one is never used.

2 - SFINAE works with template parameter of the function; not with template parameter of the class. So if you try something as

```
template<typename U1, typename U2, typename = decltype(T1_t() + T2_t())>
    static char test(void *);
```

SFINAE doesn't works because you're not using `U1` and `U2` (template parameter of the method) but with `T1_t()` and `T2_t()`, so `T1` and `T2`, template parameters of the class.

So I suggest the use of a `using` `Rr` to remove reference

```
      template <typename T>
      using Rr = typename std::remove_reference<T>::type;
```

and, to make simpler, to use SFINAE through returned type

```
  template<typename U1, typename U2>
  static auto test(void *)
     -> decltype(std::declval<Rr<U1>>() + std::declval<Rr<U2>>() , '0');
```

**-- EDIT --**

The OP can't use `std::declval()`.

> I use mingw and for an unknown reason cannot recognize declval

So I propose a better-than-nothing trivial substitute (without `std::add_rvalue_reference<T>::type`, in case you can't use it)

```
template <typename T>
T declVal();
```

and `HasPlusT` become

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct HasPlusT
 {
   private:

      template <typename T>
      using Rr = typename std::remove_reference<T>::type;

      template<typename U1, typename U2>
      static auto test(void *)
         -> decltype(declVal<Rr<U1>>() + declVal<Rr<U2>>() , '0');

      template<typename...>
      static long test(...);

   public:
      static constexpr bool value
         = IsSameT<decltype(test<T1,T2>(nullptr)),char>::value;
 };
```

**-- EDIT 2 --**

The OP say

> what modifications are needed to support check for class templates? I try to do this for a class A but seems not to work. See in the initial post.

Isn't a problem of class templates.

The problem is that your `operator+()` for `A` classes

```
friend A<T> operator + (A<T> & a1, A<T> & a2)
 { return a1.add(a2); }
```

is unusual because is (correctly) a `friend` function of the class but receive references (left-references), not constant, to `A<T>` objects (usually are `const` references; the first value can be a value not referenced), modify the first received argument (dangerous) and return it by copy.

So the `HasPlusT` class fail because `std::declval()` return a r-value referenced object that doesn't match an `operator+` that ask for l-values.

I **strongly** suggest you to modify `operator+()` as follows (`a1` and `a2` `const`)

```
  friend A<T> operator+ (A<T> const & a1, A<T> const & a2)
   { A<T> ret{a1}; return ret.add(a2); }
```

or, maybe better, as follows (`a1` without `&`, `a2` `const`)

```
  friend A<T> operator+ (A<T> a1, A<T> const & a2)
   { return a1.add(a2); }
```

and you'll see that `HasPlusT` works again.

Comment: Hm. There's a reason all those type-traits inherit from `std::bool_constant`.

Comment: Declval is not supported in my compiler and I try this alternative..But I try to understand where is the error

Comment: @GeorgeTsoumplekas: `std::declval`'s implementation is completely trivial; it's just the declaration. But you really should say if you don't even have a minimal C++11 implementation.

Comment: @GeorgeTsoumplekas - No `std::declval`? Really? Have you included `utility`? Which compiler are you using?

Comment: I use mingw  and for an unknown reason cannot recognize declval

Comment: @GeorgeTsoumplekas - Answer modified with a better-than-nothing substitute for `std::declval()`

Comment: @max66  what modifications are needed to support check for class templates? I try to do this for a class A<T> but seems not to work. See in the initial post

Comment: @GeorgeTsoumplekas - I'm surprised: it should works also with redefined `operator+()`. In this moment I can't but, within hours, I'll try to understand what's wrong.

Comment: Ιt works for normal classes. But for classes template does not work. Thank you for support

Comment: @GeorgeTsoumplekas - It's a reference problem; not a template-class problem; your `operator+()` is all but canonical; "Edit 2" added in answer.

Comment: Thank you the answer.But I am little confused. declval in any case will return r-value.What rule is applied and is needed the first argument to be a value and no the two of them?  Why when use a temp object for add (fist approach)there is no problem .. It is strange for me

Comment: @getsoubl - I don't understandn what do you exactly want to know; anyway... a r-value is compatible with a function that accept both a `T const &` (by const reference) object or a `T` (by copy) object.

Comment: Great. I miss the point that r-value is compatible with const &